# How to get old hotfix KB2888853?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ftp, sftp, windows-update

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 running and want to install KB2888853 which is not available any more to download (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2888853/fix-the-supplied-message-is-incomplete-error-when-you-use-an-ftps-clie)
Somehow Windows Update hasn't installed this update. I checked the file versions mentioned in the above article, server versions of Ftpconfigext.dll and Ftpsvc.dll are older than the versions mentioned in the hotfix.
Is there any other way to get this update? Thanks

Comment: Can you verify this after installing the latest monthly rollup (May, 2019) of Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: This update is installed but the two DLLs are not updated, "2019-05 Preview of Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows Server 2008 R2 for x64-based Systems (KB4499178)"

Answer (score 2):

You can download it from this archive page: http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?autocom=downloads&showfile=19663